# My PHP RegEx does not work with < character

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace this:

```
<!-- <#Window#> -->
...<div>Something</div>...
<!-- </#Window#> -->
```

with this:

```
<!-- <#Window#> -->
...Some new <span>...
<!-- </#Window#> -->
```

I try with [RegEx](http://regex101.com/r/tK2gU1/2), and have the following expression:

```
<!-- <#Window#>\K[^<]*(?=<!-- </#Window#> --!>)
```

It works if there are no `<` characters between the start and end of the sequence. (without div, span, html tags)

How can I get this to work?

**Edited:**

I try with Avinash Raj and vks solution with PHP and it works only if 1 line is between start and end sequence. Don't know why?

```
$contents = file_get_contents($FileNamePHP);
$search = '~(<!--\s*<#Window#>\s*-->.)(.*?)(.<!--\s*<\/#Window#>\s*-->)~';
$code = RenderGridWindow($TableName, $WindowOptions);
$contents = preg_replace($search, $code, $contents, -1, $count);
```

For better explanation, when source code is

```
<!-- <#Window#> -->
<div><span>something</span></div>
<!-- </#Window#> -->
```

works, but not if

```
<!-- <#Window#> -->
<div>
<span>something</span>
</div>
<!-- </#Window#> -->
```

**Edited2**

It works with Avinash Raj PHP code.

Comment: Have you tried the following expression: `\<[a-zA-Z0-9]+\>(.*)\</[a-zA-Z0-9]+\>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
/<!-- <#Window#>[^\n]*\n\K.*(?=\n\s*<!-- </#Window#> --!>)/gs
```

Use the above regex to match the chars which are present in between the string `<!-- <#Window#> -->` and replace the matched characters with the string you want.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tK2gU1/3)

```
<?php
$string = <<<EOT
    <!-- <#Window#> --!>
   asdasd
   <div>
   dggfgf
   gdxsghxgf
    <!-- </#Window#> --!>
EOT;
$pattern = "~<!-- <#Window#>[^\n]*\n\K.*(?=\n\s*<!-- </#Window#> --!>)~s";
$replacement = "       ...Some new <span>...";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Output:

```
    <!-- <#Window#> --!>
   ...Some new <span>...
    <!-- </#Window#> --!>
```

Comment: It works in regex101.com but not in PHP. I am trying to figure it out why. It works only when 1 line is between start and end sequence.

Comment: what was your replacement string?

Answer (score 0):

```
(<!--\s*<#Window#>\s*-->.)(.*?)(.<!--\s*<\/#Window#>\s*-->)
```

You can try this.Replacement will be

```
$1<urcontent>$3
```

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/3

Comment: It works in regex101.com but not in PHP. I am trying to figure it out why. It works only when 1 line is between start and end sequence.